# How do i access a edittext box on a listview row

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a list view with edittext on each row. If a user clicks on a rowhowcan i access that particular edittext?

Comment: Here is an exact example for your problem: [Android Focusable EditText inside ListView](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/)

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize `EditText`'s `onClickListener()` inside your adapter's `getView()` method, right where you inflate this `EditText`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the `EditText` boxes were created during runtime, you can use `setId(int)` when creating them.  Then, through your `ListView`, you can use `findViewById(int id)` to retrieve it in the future.  So the full call would be like `EditText myEditText = (EditText) myListView.findViewById(1)` would retrieve the box who's ID you set to `1`.

If you create them through XML, then you can assign the ID to them in the xml that you can easily remember.  Afterwards, you can use `findViewById(int id)` the same way as before but use the ID references in the generated R file.

Answer (score 0):

I want you to use listAdapter class.
You must make your own class which extends the BaseAdapter class.
Then make a listItem class which contains a EditText Control.
And deal events of EditText in the class.
Then you must add the class as the arrays of class into the listAdapter class.
And override the getView function of BaseAdapter class.